# How to create working callback on LegendItem in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to call a `CustomJS` callback on a `Legend` or a `LegendItem`, when the `visible` attribute of a renderer changes.

I have this minimal example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, Legend
output_notebook()

p = figure(width=300, height=300, tools='pan')

p.add_layout(Legend(click_policy='hide'))

p.line([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5], legend_label="a")
p.legend.items[0].js_on_change("visible", CustomJS(code="""console.log("Output LegendItem")"""))
p.x_range.js_on_change("start", CustomJS(code="""console.log("Output XRange")"""))

show(p)
```

[image: Callback works an xrange and not on legend item]

When I use the `PanTool` I can see a the text `"Output XRange"`. If I click on the legend and hide the line, the log shows no message.

How to modify the code, to call a callback, if the `Legend` is clicked or a `LegendItems` hides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the visible attribute of a renderer changes

In that case you should set your callback on the `visible` property of the renderer directly, instead of trying to go some indirect route through the legend.

```py
r = p.line(...)
r.js_on_change("visible", CustomJS(...))
```